# Why does Angular 7 resets manipulated element text content

Tags: angular, dom, data-manipulation, angular7

I'am just new to Angular, so please go "easy" on me.
I have a common TypeScript class for I18n for localized changes (e.g. text value on an element) at runntime. I am using it in other (non-Angular) projects as well.

If I include my own class for handling i18n, it changes the text accordingly, but after that, in angular core it will change it back to the original state. Why does angular do that. It is not bind?

Here are the code:

```
<div *ngFor="let module of modules()" (mouseup)="route(module.key)" class="{{module.i18nKey}}">
  <div><i class="{{module.iconClass}}"></i></div>
  <div attr.data-i18n-key="{{module.i18nKey}}" data-i18n-module="module">!!!localize this!!!</div>
</div>
```

I'am confused. The i18n library adds an attribute called data-i18n-translated and sets it to true und sets the localized text. After that, Angular resets the translated value to false and sets the text to the original value !!!localize this!!!

Why? How can I prevent this? I am not changing attr.data-i18n-key at all?

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when angular change-detection kicks in, it recreates the DOM elements which are handled by the `ngForOf` directive and your external library didn't know about that.

A first solution would be to use the `trackBy` option for your `ngForOf` directive, this will prevent angular to recreated the DOM elements unless the value returned by the function changes.

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let module of modules(); trackBy: trackByKey">
</div>
```

Component:

```
...
public trackByKey(index: number, value: any)
{
  return value.i18nKey
}
...
```

Another solution would be to rerun your external i18n parser if the change-detection is run for your component.